# How do I retrieve data from an inner collection through an outer collection in Java?

Tags: java, collections

If there is a collection

```
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> hm = 
                             new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

how to retrieve data from `al` through `hm`?

ex: I need `hm`->2=-`al`->4

Comment: Could you explain your example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would say something like the following:

```
hm.get(string).get(integer);
```

If you were to divide it up, it's like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arlist = hm.get(string); // This will return the string's hash map value
int value = arlist.get(index); // This will return the ArrayList's index's element
```

For more information on HashMap's `get()`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get(java.lang.Object)

For more information on ArrayList's `get()`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)